# Unable to change bootstrap navbar "color". Can change other elements inside class?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to change the "color" attribute on the bootstrap navigation bar.  I can change every other feature of the element ("text-decoration", etc ) but, for some reason I can not override the color?

```
<nav class="nav navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#defaultNavbar1" aria-expanded="false"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="defaultNavbar">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="[-- VAR.URL --]/sage.html">SACRED HERBS<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>

                       ...


                <li><a href="[-- VAR.URL --] /specials.html">SALE</a></li>
</ul>

  </div>

</div></nav>
```

And, here is the CSS I am using:

```
.navbar-default {
  background-image:none;
  width:100%;
}


.navbar-nav {
    background-color: #29bbdb;
    width: 100%;
    }


.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight:600;
    text-decoration:underline;
    background-color: transparent;

 }
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  font-weight:600;
  color: #D1D4D4;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration:overline;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried just create your own class with appropriate styles and add it to navbar? Not just trying to override the existed one?

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I did try this.  It did not work.  What is odd is that the CSS allows me to change all the other elements - I can change "text-decoration", "font-weight" etc...just not the "color"

Comment: hmm, if you want to change the color of navbar itself, maybe it will be better if you try to change `background-color`, not the `color` style?

Comment: no , i am trying to change the color of the text not the bar thus "color" is used.

Comment: can you explain what text exactly? maybe you create a fiddle so i can have a look?

Comment: the text color is for the navigation links.  the navigation bar itself is fine, it is the color of the text of the links that I am trying to change.

Comment: please create a fiddle

Comment: thanks Andrew...i have solved this issue, now on to the next ~

Comment: could you explain what was happening and how did you resolve it?